# 15.04: Ugly icons in the Launcher

Tags: launcher, icons, 15.04

Using 15.04 since yesterday, one of the things I note is a number of icons portrayed strangely by the Launcher. Here are a few examples:

[image]

I thought this was a resolution issue but zooming in one can see these icons are just "ugly". Other programmes like Eclipse, Gimp or Firefox get nice icons as before.

Can anything be made about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. It has already been reported. You can keep track of this bug on Launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1446081

It might be best to mark yourself as "also affected" and see if they need anymore information.

Answer (score 3):

This might be because of some changes in **GTK 3.14** regarding icon themes (sizes, scaling, etc.) and because that particular application does not have a compatible icon size.

You can try another (more complete and up-to-date) icon theme like **Numix** (https://github.com/numixproject) or **Nitrux** (http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=154496) to see if it helps.

Otherwise, you might try and open the *.desktop file for that application (in `/usr/share/applications/` or `/usr/local/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`) and change the icon specified there to a more compatible alternative.

Comment: This is valuable information. I have tried a few other icon themes but these also are rendered in an "ugly" way, it seems that some resizing algorithm is failing. The high contrast theme provides a good example. As for alternative icons I do not have none.

Comment: I personally keep a simple shell script to replace a number of odd icon filenames with a alternative icons -- as close as I can get in my favorite icon theme. A simple example might be: `sudo sed -i 's/Icon=odd-text-editor-icon/Icon=text-editor/g' "/usr/share/applications/odd-text-editor.desktop"`